# Cannot save structure into mongodb with golang (only empty records created)

Tags: mongodb, go, database, nosql

I have the following structure

```
type Result struct {
    nid         string
    timestamp   int64
    hexhash     string
    addr        string
}
```

which I want to save into mongodb:

I create it

```
r := Result{hex_id, int64(msg.timestamp.Unix()), hexhash, msg.addr.String()}
```

And test if it is created correctly:

```
fmt.Println(r)
```

Which gives me result I'm expecting:

> {b8da3f19d1318af6879976c1eea66c78c48e1144 1421417252
>   65072917F19D7F4C4B54C9C66A3EB31F77012981 127.0.0.1:65290}

Then I save it into mongo:

```
h.c.Insert(r)
```

But in mongo i see only empty records:

> db.data.find()
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("54b91a268da6c829a412cd4d") }

The h in the code above defined as

```
type Handler struct {
    storage     map[string]Message
    new_msg     chan Message
    new_inp     chan Input
    c           *mgo.Collection
}
```

and

```
h.c = session.DB(DATABASE).C(COLLECTION)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fileds of your record need to be public for other packages (like the MongoDB wrapper) to see them. Rename the fields like this:

```
type Result struct {
    Nid         string
    Timestamp   int64
    Hexhash     string
    Addr        string
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've be struggling with this for hours!

Comment: 7 years later and I just want to say thank you!